# Does passing a reference type in props make React.memo useless?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, memoization

Suppose I have a `PersonCard` component, which receives props, and renders a card showing the person's information.

```
interface PersonProps { 
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string
}

const PersonCard: React.FC<PersonProps> = (firstName, lastName) => {
    // render the things
}
```

Now, if I were to use `React.memo` to prevent unnecessary re-rendering of this component, it would look like this:

```
const PersonCard: React.FC(<PersonProps>) => 
    React.memo(({firstName, lastName}) => {
    // render the things
    }
)
```

And this, to my understanding, would work: if my component was called twice with the same `firstName` and `lastName`, it would not re-render.

---

Now, my question arises when we add a reference type to the mix:

```
interface PersonProps { 
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    hobbies: Array<string>
}

const PersonCard: React.FC(<PersonProps>) => 
    React.memo(({firstName, lastName, hobbies}) => {
    // render the things
    }
)
```

In this case `React.memo` does a shallow comparison (as its default behavior), and will not work on the `hobbies` array.

Therefore, `PersonCard` will always re-render, even if `firstName`, `lastName` and `hobbies` do not change, because it will think `hobbies` changed:
this is effectively the same as not having `React.memo` at all.

So, my question is this: **Am I wrong, or having any reference type passed as a prop without specifying a deep comparison callback completely nullifies the point of React.memo?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you are correct: passing one or more reference types as a prop to a memoized component will prevent memoization, *assuming the reference changes between every render* (which is often the case). To play devil's advocate, here are a couple scenarios where you *don't* expect the reference to change between each render:

#### Static Values

If you pass a static reference to a `const` as a prop, you can reasonably expect that it won't change between renders, and should be safely memoized.

```
const IDS = [1, 2, 3];

const App = () => (
  <MyMemoizedComponent ids={IDS} />
);
```

This works with static `let` variables as well, with the caveat that the memoized component will rerender if the reference changes.

```
let IDS = [1, 2, 3];
IDS = IDS.slice(); // this would trigger a rerender
```

#### refs

Static values are generally avoided when working with components in favor of a ref. When using a ref where you don't expect the value of `.current` to change frequently, you can still get the benefit of memoization.

```
const App = () => {
  const idsRef = React.useRef([1, 2, 3]);

  return (
    <MyMemoizedComponent ids={idsRef.current} />
  );
}
```

#### useMemo

`React.memo` and `React.useMemo` aren't mutually exclusive! You can memoize a value with `useMemo` to prevent it from breaking memoization.

```
const App = () => {
  const idsMemo = React.useMemo(() => [1, 2, 3], []);

  return (
    <MyMemoizedComponent ids={idsMemo} />
  );
};
```

These examples are a bit contrived, but you can imagine a scenario where the data isn't initialized locally but is instead fetched over the network, something like

```
const App = ({ path }) => {
  const ids = React.useMemo(() => fetchFromNetwork(path), [path]);

  return (
    <MyMemoizedComponent ids={ids} />
  );
};
```

So, in summary, passing one or more references types as a prop to a memoized component will *usually* break memoization. If you expect the reference type to change value frequently (~once per render), just drop the memoization, it's causing extra work with no benefit. If you *don't* expect it to change frequently, memoize it and only update the reference when the inner value changes (or, as you noted, provide a custom deep equality comparison function to `React.memo`).

Answer (score 3):

To build on the accepted answer, `React.memo` accepts an optional second argument, which allows you to customize the logic of the props comparison. For deep equality, you can use `isEqual` from `lodash`, or alternatively write your own deep comparison function.

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
import { isEqual } from "lodash";

const MyComponent = props => {
 // component logic and rendering 
};

export default memo(MyComponent, isEqual);
```

```
/**
 * Function that performs deep equality between prop instances
 * @param {P} prevProps previous instance of props
 * @param {P} nextProps next instance of props
 * @returns {boolean} true if props are equal
 */
const customIsEqual = <P>(prevProps: P, nextProps: P): boolean => {
  // deep equality check; true if props are equal
};
```